# How to test a nested JSON data present in JSON file in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, unit-testing, testing

Currently I'm using this,it is not working for nested JSON file

```
 public function testitemExists(){
        $response = $this->json('GET','/api/items');
        $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonFragment(['category'=>'drinks']);
    }
```

```
{
 "category" :"drinks",
  "items":[{
"item1":"mojito",
"item2":"cocacola"
}
]

}
```

how can I test item1 => mojito  present or not

Answer (score 2):

Try this (using Laravel 8.x):

```
    $response
    ->assertOk()
    ->assertJson(
        fn (AssertableJson $json) =>
        $json->has('category')
            ->has(
                'items',
                1,
                fn ($json) =>
                $json->where('item1', "mojito")
                    ->where('item2', 'cocacola')
            )
    );
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#scoping-json-collection-assertions).

Comment: thank you! are we able to use callable for assertJsonMissing? or any way to achieve it? as having an error when using `assertJsonMissing`:   Found unexpected JSON fragment

Comment: No, Unfortunately it just accepts array as parameter:
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.html#method_assertJsonMissing